# How to fix the Cydia data problem?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, ipad, cydia

My iPad 2 is jailbroken and running iOS 5.0.1. When I open up Cydia, it shows me a message : `The package com.teiron.pphelper needs to be reinstalled. But I can't find an archive for it.`
How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This may work.  Install MobileTerminal and enter:

```
su (and enter password, alpine by default)

dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq com.teiron.pphelper

dpkg --configure -a
```

If this doesn't work, let me know, and I'll look for something else... Hope this helps!

Comment: This should work.

Comment: Do you mean to find a app whose name is Mobile Terminal and enther the command ?

Comment: @LeonPak Yes, that's what he means. If you don't have a supported device for MobileTerminal in the standard repositories, then check out my answer here to get a port for the A4 devices: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/45022/18387

Comment: Can I do this by ifunbox?

Comment: I try to update cydia to newest version（1.16），but the problem still not fix.

Comment: When i type su and password i get, /var/mobile root#
WWhat shall i type There?

Answer (score -1):

It's easyer to find right repo for com.teiron.pphelper, add it to cydia and than will everything be ok again.